# Open external URL in new window with h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, redirect, commandlink, new-window, external-url

I would like to click a link and redirect to an external URL in a new window.

```
<h:commandLink value="Test" target="_blank" action="#{bean.openWindow}" />
```

```
public String openWindow() {
    return "http://www.google.com";
}
```

But it is just not working. My browser has opened a new window. But the window is showing the same page instead of the external URL.

Comment: The return value of the action method is expected to be a navigation case outcome which is untrue in your case. If no bean logic is to be executed upon clicking the link, then simply use `<h:outputLink value="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Test Popup</h:outputLink>` instead.

Comment: The outputLink is worked for display google now. Thx Tiny. How about if I would like to redirect to some page contains some logic. How can I do? I know I should use commandLink this moment. When I changed to public String PopupWindow() {return "popupWindow";} and keep the commandLink part. I also have the page called popupWindow.jspx. But still not working. The page popup a new window, but display the same page instead of popupWindow.jspx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4317723/1391249 (I am not practically aware of old JSPX).

Comment: public void openWindow() {
      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect("http://www.google.com");
}